# вызов функции ежесекундно в JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго

Сразу скажу, вопрос отличается от тысяч аналогичных в интернете

```
//function 1
$(".div1").click(function(){
    ...очень много кода
});
```

можно ли каким образом вызвать вызов функции ежесекундно, в JQ коде?

```
//function 1
$(".div1").click(function calculate(){
    ...очень много кода
});

//вот это, не работает. с простыми JS работает, но в JQ нет
setTimeout(calculate(), 1000);
```

Comment: JQ - не язык прогрммирования, а библиотека на JS. Если что-то работает в JS, но не работает в JQ - проверяйте ваш код. Где-то есть ошибка

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719926/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b6%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setTimeout](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#settimeout) не будет выполнять ваш код "ежесекундно". Он выполняется через заданное кол-во секунд, 1 раз. Следует использовать [setInterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval)

`calculate()` судя по всему у Вас имеется только в обработчике `.click`, соответственно `setTimeout(calculate(), 1000);` ни к чему и не приводит, он не может видеть эту функцию, её нет для `setTimeout()`.

Если я правильно понял задачу, то можно использовать [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). Примерно так:

```js
$(".div1").click(function calculate(){
  console.log("alert");
});

setInterval(function() {
  $(".div1").trigger("click");
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">1111</div>
```

Comment: много узнал! спс. по задаче именно так и получилось

Comment: либо просто сделать _calculate_ обычной функцией