# Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

Допустим, я написал функцию:

```
function foo() {
    alert("Hello, world!");
}
```

Почему когда я пытаюсь вызвать ее спустя некоторое время, она вместо этого вызывается сразу же?

```
setTimeout(foo(), 10000);
```

И то же самое - с обработчиками событий? Пытался делать вот так:

```
el.onclick = foo();
el.addEventListener("click", foo());
createButton({
    name: "show alert",
    onClick: foo(),
});
```

Comment: *Я уже несколько раз натыкался на эту ошибку на сайте и каждый раз во мне боролись желание помочь и нежелание тратить время на такую фигню. Теперь такие вопросы можно будет закрывать как дубликаты.*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Возможно, вы написали скобки около имени функции - `foo()` - случайно. А возможно, вы думаете что именно этими скобками функция отличается от переменной. В любом случае, ошибка скрыта именно тут.

Кратко: уберите лишние скобки и все заработает.

---

Javascript вычисляет выражения изнутри-наружу (как и многие другие языки). Очевидные примеры из математики: в выражении `2 + 2 * 2` сначала выполняется умножение, а потом - сложение, а в выражении `(2 + 2) * 2` - наоборот.

Когда вы пишите `foo()` - это оператор вызова функции. Это- такая же часть выражения как и любая математическая операция. И если где-то внутри выражения есть вызов `foo()` - то функция `foo` будет вызвана независимо от того что написано снаружи.

Так, в примере `setTimeout(foo(), 10000);` **сначала** вызывается `foo()`, а потом результат вызова `foo()` (обычно это какой-нибудь `undefined`) передается в `setTimeout`: `setTimeout(undefined, 10000)`. С точки зрения интерпретатора Javascript это не ошибка: он же не знает что такое `foo`, он просто послушно делает что вы ему сказали.

Если вам не нужно вызывать функцию - то не надо ее вызывать. Просто убираем скобки около имени функции - и теперь она передается как есть, без вызова:

```
setTimeout(foo, 10000);
el.onclick = foo;
el.addEventListener("click", foo);
createButton({
    name: "show alert",
    onClick: foo,
});
```

Вызовут ее уже в другом месте, когда придет время. (Кстати, такая переданная куда-то функция обычно называется колбеком, callback или функцией обратного вызова).

Если вас волнует вопрос как в таком случае интерпретатор отличит функцию от переменной, то ответ на него - а ему и не нужно их отличать, имя функции - это разновидность имени переменной.