# Таймер js не работает

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте,не работает таймер js,подключения файла проверял,всё работает,пишу точно так же,как было указано на различных источниках,Js не отключён,в чём может быть проблема?Заранее спасибо.

```
var id = setInterval("myFunct_1()", 1000);
var counter = 0;
function myFunct_1 () {
conter++;
alert("Секунд прошло:" + counter);
if(counter == 10) clearInterval(id);
};
```

Comment: var id = setInterval(myFunct_1(), 1000) - кавычек недолжно быть

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Comment: `setInterval(myFunct_1, 1000);`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719926/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b6%d0%b5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var id = setInterval(myFunct_1, 1000);
var counter = 0;

function myFunct_1 () {
  counter++;
  alert("Секунд прошло:" + counter);
  if(conter == 10) clearInterval(id);
}
```

1. Пользуйтесь консолью, там было написано, что "conter" не найдено
2. Передавайте функции в аргумент без кавычек и без "()"

Comment: только вы забыли id назначить

Comment: спасибо, исправил

Comment: Спасибо за помощь