# Вызов метода класса с помощью setInterval

Tags: javascript, ооп, setinterval

Здравствуйте, вопрос у меня такой, ну изменять позицию экземпляра класса, есть метод Move, который изменяет позицию, хочу вызвать его с определённой задержкой в цикле

```
while (car1.currentPosition < screen.width - 10){
 div.style.left = car1.currentPosition + 'px';
 setInterval(car1.move(), 1000);
}
```

Car1 тестовый экземпляр, setInterval(car1.move(), 1000) - Данная конструкция не работает, вылетает всё разом без задержки. 
Вот и вопрос как изменить вызов setIntervalдля того чтобы всё работало

Comment: setTimeout(car1.move(), 1000);

Comment: SetTimeout не подошёл

Comment: К сведению: [Потеря контекста вызова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/178779), [Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/719926/178779)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719926/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b6%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решила данная конструкция

```
function initialization(vechicle) {

setInterval(function () {
    vechicle.move();
    div.style.left = vechicle.currentPosition + 'px';
    if (vechicle.currentPosition === screen.width - 100) {
        vechicle.setCurrentPosition(0);
        div.style.left = '0px';
        count++;
    }
}, 5);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while (car1.currentPosition < screen.width - 10){
 div.style.left = car1.currentPosition + 'px';
 setInterval(function(){car1.move()}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Вам нужно прочитать про стек трейс и понять как работает javascript внутри движка. Метод while синхронный и будет выполняться пока не завершится в то время как setInterval асинхронный - он упадет в web APIs и будет ждать пока event loop его не вызовет (иными словами пока не пройдет весь стек трейс синхронных функций). 
Попробуйте использовать самовызывающиеся setTimeout (что-то типа этого):

```
setTimeout(function timeout() {
        if (car1.currentPosition < screen.width - 10) {
            div.style.left = car1.currentPosition + 'px';
            setTimeout(timeout, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000)
```

Answer (score -2):

Необходимо убрать скобки. Вот так:

```
while (car1.currentPosition < screen.width - 10){
 div.style.left = car1.currentPosition + 'px';
 setInterval(car1.move, 1000);
}
```

UPDATE:

Тогда в вышем случае лучше так:

```
while (car1.currentPosition < screen.width - 10){
  div.style.left = car1.currentPosition + 'px';
  setTimeout(function call() {
    car1.move();
    setTimeout(call, 1000);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Данный код ждет, пока выполнется перемещение элемента.

Comment: Тоже не работает, страница вообще зависла

Comment: Тот же эффект, зависает всё

Comment: Опишите проблему подробнее.