# Как устроен синтаксис обработчика $(window).on('scroll')?

Tags: jquery

1) Есть такая функция c параметром:

```
function check_Smth () {
  ..
};
```

Хочу чтобы она вызывалась при скроллинге страницы. Пишу:

```
$window.on('scroll', check_Smth});
```

Всё работает.

2) Хочу добавить параметр для универсальности:

```
function check_Smth (param) {
  ..
};
```

Вызываю обработчик:

```
$window.on('scroll', check_Smth(param1)});
```

Не работает ((

Пришлось переделать в такой формат:

```
$window.on('scroll', function () {
        check_Smth(param1);
 });
```

Нет понимания почему не работает второй вариант. Кто-нибудь может объяснить доступным языком, подробно, почему он не работает ?

Comment: потому что там задается функция-обработчик, а не кусок кода, который будет выполняться. Именно третьим вариантом и надо

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/719926/227016)

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле, в [документации](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) все довольно неплохо описано. Однако, постараюсь объяснить простым языком.

Когда вы создаете такой код:

```
$window.on('scroll', function () {
    check_Smth(param1);
});
```

Вы делаете function declaration. Иными словами, вы определяете функцию, которая будет вызываться каждый раз, когда срабатывает событие, при этом не вызывая саму функцию.

То же самое происходит, когда Вы делаете так:

```
function check_Smth () {
  ..
}; 

$window.on('scroll', check_Smth});
```

Сначала вы декларируете функцию, затем Вы ее "аттачите", но не вызываете ее.

Когда же Вы делаете так:

```
$window.on('scroll', check_Smth(param1)});
```

Вы выполняете вызов функции при попытке аттача хэндлера для события scroll.

В данном случае Ваша функция выполнится и вернет undefined.

Далее, этот undefined и заатачится как хендлер к событию onScroll:

- -> попытка attach'a handler'a для onScroll события
- -> вызов переданной function
- -> function возвращает 'undefined'
- -> ничего не работает

Решить данную проблему можно было бы еще и так:

```
function check_Smth(param1) {
  return function() {
      //...
  }
}; 

$window.on('scroll', check_Smth(param1)});
```

В этом случае, у Вас вызовется функция, которая возвращает функцию, которая и станет обработчиком, а не undefined.

По большому счету, это вопрос разницы [function call vs function reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference)

Кроме того, конструкция:

```
$window.on('scroll', check_Smth(param1)});
```

С точки зрения использования jQuery не является верной, так как **param1** в данном случае будет содержать [event](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event), а не нужный Вам параметр.

P.S. подобные вопросы, кстати, часто ставят в тупик людей на собеседованиях =) Вроде и понятно, почему не работает, а объяснить не могут =)