# JavaScript без быдлокодинга

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, reactjs

Возник вопрос по поводу изучения чистого JS и фреймворков.
Не раз являлся свидетелем: на форумах более-менее опытные разработчики пытаются донести, что учить jQuery сходу (или любую другую библиотеку, не говоря уже о фреймворке) - это путь в никуда.
Так вот, я учил чистый JS, прочитал пару книг, написал свои модальные окна, табы, заезженный ТоДо лист и т.д. и т.п. и решил пойти в Vue.
Прекрасно понимаю, как что работает и почему. Но мне не даёт покоя одна вещь: как понять, что я на достаточном уровне для изучения той или иной библиотеки?
Этот вопрос возникает не просто так, а когда я сталкиваюсь с чем-то, чего не знаю, как, например, `async / await`. Я, честно говоря, про него только и узнал, пока учил эту библиотеку...

Вопрос такой: что точно нужно знать, чтобы я уверенно мог идти учить Н-ный фреймворк-библиотеку, и меня не мучила совесть?
Я просто хочу увидеть список того, что нужно понимать и уметь применять железно.
Потому что "основы JS" - понятие довольно широкое, и не всегда понятно, что конкретно в себя включает.

Comment: я, например, сначала познакомился с jQuery, и уже много позже взялся за js. Ничего не потерял. Напротив этот фреймворк позволил мне решать 99% тривиальных задач быстро и эффективно.

Comment: Учить базис языка действительно необязательно. Да, общаясь с коллегами которые его знают вы возможно будете чувствовать свои проседания в понимании происходящего, но не более того, да и явление это временное. Без быдлокодинга не обойтись в любом случае, практика, практика и ещё раз практика, чем больше делаете, тем больше вопросов возникает, тем больше углубляетесь не в решение, а в проблему, тем глубже понимание языка. Не бывает так, что "прочитал и все понял". Бесспорно, понимание языка - плюс, но не то что бы обязательная часть программы.

Comment: Когда у тебя возникнет желание написать свою  библиотеку и фрейм и будешь иметь представления, как это можно сделать, ты  поймешь, что  JS знаешь достаточно...  Пользоваться чужими достижениями не имея свох, ты профи никогда не станешь. Это сгубо мое личное мнение...  Изучаю JS  с лета, и ни сточки на JQ не написал...

Comment: возьми тот же vue - и прям по полочкам пойми как он работает...

Comment: Пару минут назад отвечала на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/774272/Есть-ли-возможность-плавно-удалить-класс-у-элемента/774368?noredirect=1#comment1210483_774368). На самом деле, все зависит от ваших целей. Самое главное - это умение быстро разбираться в новых фреймворках, а без знания основ это будет не просто сделать. А мода и фреймворки всегда будут меняться.

Comment: По опыту: самые необходимые основы - это работа с переменными. Если вы знаете как создавать переменные - ваш код будет выглядеть лучше 99% jquery-лапши. После этого можно браться уже и за jquery.

Comment: А, ну еще нужно знать как передаются функции и как не терять `this` - но это проще чем уметь применять переменные. Кроме того, у нас уже есть канонические ответы на эту тему: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535030/178779), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/719926/178779).

Comment: Вот вам мой совет: никого не стоит слушать, ставите себе задачу (написать веб приложение) и пишите пока вас всё не устроит. Так как последнее условие недостижимо, вы автоматически попадает в вечный цикл рефакторинга, таким образом прокачиваете свой скилл

Answer (score 6):

Приведу себя в пример: я в начале прошлого года даже не задумывался об изучении фреймворка, мне хватало обычного javascript, но когда я понял, что по большей части работаю с DOM-ом и каждый раз (с новым проектом) переношу повторяющийся код (касающийся архитектуры приложения в целом) я стал уверен в том, что пора изучить фреймворк, чтобы писать только бизнес-логику и быстрее решать задачи, связанные с работой.

Я не пожалел - многие задачи упростились, время на их выполнение стало тратиться меньше. Выбрал Vue.js, низкий порог входа, достаточно прост в изучении и это довольно мощный фреймворк.

Кроме того, я придерживаюсь мнения, что знать основы JS обязательно - без этого никуда.

И проще говоря, если ты знаешь:

1. HTML
2. CSS
3. Javascript

на бозовом уровне и если ты во фронтенд-разработке не новичок - ты можешь спокойно учить фреймворки/библиотеки и тебя не должна никогда мучить совесть за это.

Comment: Полностью согласна, основы совершенно точно необходимы.