# Есть ли возможность плавно удалить класс у элемента

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="a b"></div>
```

Как плавно удалить класс `<a>` методами jquery? Имеется ввиду, что есть визуальный элемент с классом `<a>`. Удаляя класс `<a>` нужно чтобы этот элемент плавно исчез

Comment: вот и сделайте, чтобы он исчез, а потом удаляйте

Comment: понятно - спасибо. Сначала убираем элемент, а потом класс, отвечающий за отображение этого элемента.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.a').click(function() {
    $(".a").fadeOut()
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a b">нажми, и я исчезну...</div>
```

Comment: как всё просто (+) а можете объяснить чайнику, то есть мне, почему сейчас так презрительно отзываются о JQuery

Comment: написал, что плюсую, а плюс забыл поставить :) исправил

Comment: @ Alexandr_TT если кратко то (мое мнение) мода, большое количество новичков и сдвиг на приложения. Мода на мою жизнь так сильно нигде и никогда не влияла, на этой неделе модно писать так, а на следующей так уже никто не пишет. И конечно же, вечные поиски идеального фреймворка который может всё(а в идеале, чтобы он сам тестировал, сам думал, мгновенно загружался, везде поддерживался, сам обновлялся, искал баги и фиксил их). Многое можно сделать абсолютно разными инструментами, но чтобы они хорошо работали надо их хорошо поддерживать, изучать и тестировать.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. примерно тоже самое и в SVG/ Ищут, ищут волшебную палочку, взмахнув которой все должно решиться. Но не понимая основ, городят такие километры листинга с библиотеками и всё равно не работает, а хотя всё решается порою в одну строчку. Моё твердое убеждение, сначала нужно научиться вручную делать, а потом уж библиотеки применять.