# Node JS, return из модуля

Tags: javascript, node.js

Добрый день. Я новичок в Node , сильно не критикуйте.
Столкнулся с проблемой при возврате значения функции при вызове из модуля.

Например есть модуль:

```
function GetTableData() {


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: setup.host,
    user: setup.user,
    password: setup.password,
    database: setup.database
});

connection.connect();
var query = connection.query("SELECT * FROM tables", function (error, result) {
    if (error) { console.log(error.message); throw error; }

    jdata = JSON.stringify(result);

    console.log('mod_mysql_GetTables:AppData:' + jdata);
    return jdata;

});

connection.end(function () {
        console.log('Connection Close!');

    });
function GetTest(){
    var x =5 ;
    return x;
}

module.exports.GetTableData = GetTableData();
module.exports.GetTest = GetTest();
```

Этот модуль я вызываю в основном файла index.js по средствам require()

```
var mod_mysql = require('./mod_mysql');
var tables = mod_mysql.GetTableData;
console.log(tables);
```

**В итоге я получаю  undefined**

Делаю тоже самое с функцией GetTest, все работает нормально.

Если запускать модуль без подключения то все работает нормально, выводятся данные из mysql.

Подскажите что я делаю не так.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать скобки, когда экспортируете модуль `module.exports.GetTableData = GetTableData;`

Comment: Тогда возвращает просто [Function:GetTablesData]

Comment: ну так вызовите ее, в том месте где подключаете. `tables()`

Comment: Только что пробовал.  выдает undefined

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719926/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b6%d0%b5)

Comment: И еще: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/178779)

Comment: @PavelMayorov Спасибо вам, я разобрался почему я получал undefined. Реализовал все через callback, но остался один вопрос. Как получить результат выполнения функции в переменную? То есть, я в главном скрипте делаю так  mod_mysql.getTable(function(jdata){//что то }); как получить эту jdata в нужную мне переменную?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите, если Вы экспортируете модуль, и при этом в конце функции ставите `()`, другими словами, вызываете функцию, то Вы экспортируете не саму функцию, а результат ее выполнения.

```
var mod_mysql = require('./mod_mysql');
var tables = mod_mysql; /// без GetTableData;
console.log(tables);
```

Если же Вы, при экспорте функции, не вызываете ее, другими словами, после ее название не ставите `()`, тогда Вы экспортируете саму функцию. В результате, Вы сможете запустить ее тогда, когда посчитаете нужным. Например, :

```
var mod_mysql = require('./mod_mysql');
var tables = mod_mysql.GetTableData;
var f = tables();
console.log(f);
```

Рабочий пример: две функции экспортируются разными способами и по разному используются.
Код модуля:

```
function GetTableData(z) {
    return z+1;
}

function GetTest(){
    var x =5 ;
    return x;
}

module.exports.GetTableData = GetTableData;
module.exports.GetTest = GetTest();
```

Код исполняемого файла:

```
var mod_mysql = require('./7.js');
var GetTableData = mod_mysql.GetTableData;
var GetTest = mod_mysql.GetTest;
console.log(GetTableData(1));
console.log(GetTest);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь стало понятно вы экспорту. Проблема в том что функция возвращает undefined

Comment: А код у Вас рабочий? У меня он выдает синтаксические ошибки. Я дополнил ответ рабочим примером.

Comment: @Дмытрык обратите внимание: он пытается сделать return из асинхронной функции

Comment: Код рабочий.   console.log('mod_mysql_GetTables:AppData:' + jdata);  это работает при выполнении модуля, но значение функции почему то не возвращается

Comment: @icedev обратите внимание на ссылки в комментариях под вашим вопросом

Comment: @Дмытрык спасибо. направление понятно буду читать