# Discord JS. Return модуля

Tags: node.js, discord, return

только недавно начал изучать JS, а именно писать бота DS
Вызываю функцию, проверяю. Проверка проходит(у меня нет роли), отправляет "Access is denied." и код продолжается. 
Попробовал сделать, как тут, не получилось, не заработало: 
[Node JS, return из модуля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787042/node-js-return-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F)

I call the function, check it. The check passes, sends " Access is denied."and the code continues without stopping

Сама функция в файле funcs.js: 
Поясню, выше есть require с admins.json.

```
   function adminconfirm(message, error){
        if(!message.member.roles.has(admins.dev)){
             return message.channel.send(error);
        }
    }
```

Код, где используется данная функция :

```
    const adminconfirm = require("../utils/funcs.js");
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
let admins = require('../utils/admins.json');

module.exports.run = async (bot,message,args) => {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

    adminconfirm(message, "Access is denied.");
    if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("You didn't specify a user");
.................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты используешь `return` внутри другой функции вызова, поэтому основной код продолжает выполняться. Это равносильно тому, что если бы ты написал:

```
let variable = adminconfirm(message, "Access is denied.");
```

То в `variable` бы записались итоги выполнения твоей функции.

Для того, что бы выполнение команды прекратилось, тебе необходимо использовать `return` в теле основной функции.

```
   return adminconfirm(message, "Access is denied.");
    if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("You didn't specify a user");
.................
```

Но, т.к. в теле той функции ты выполняешь определенные проверки, то можно останавливать функцию исходя из возвращаемого значения.

```
module.exports.run = async (bot,message,args) => {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

    let allow = adminconfirm(message, "Access is denied.");  //Вызываем функцию проверки
    if(!allow) return //Если она возрвщает false , то останавливаем выполнение основной функции.
    if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("You didn't specify a user");
.................
```

```
function adminconfirm(message, error){
  if(!message.member.roles.has(admins.dev)){
        message.channel.send(error);
        return false
      }
      return true
   }
```