# Вывести переменную за пределы функции и передать её в следующую функцию

Tags: javascript, функции, переменные

Написал код для открытия текстового файла:

```
var log_txt = new XMLHttpRequest();
var online_txt;
log_txt.open("GET","log.txt");
log_txt.send();
//log_text.onload = log_txt_func(online_txt);
var online_txt = log_txt_func(online_txt);
console.log(log_txt_func(online_txt));
//console.log(date_txt);
function log_txt_func(online_txt) {
    log_txt_arr = log_txt.responseText.split("\r\n");
    log_txt_arr.forEach(date_txt_arr);
    log_txt_arr.forEach(online_txt_arr);
    var date_txt = date_txt.split(",");
    var online_txt = online_txt.split(",");
    online_txt.splice(0, 1);
    date_txt.splice(0, 1);
        function date_txt_arr(value){
            date_txt = date_txt + value.split(" ==> ")[0] + ',';
        }
        function online_txt_arr(value){
            online_txt = online_txt + value.split(" ==> ")[2] + ',';
        }
    //console.log(online_txt);
    //console.log(date_txt);
    return online_txt;
    //return date_txt;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    let online = new liteChart("chart");
    online.setLabels(date_txt);
    online.addLegend({"name": "Online", "stroke": "#3759d7", "fill": "#fff", "values": online_txt});
    let div = document.getElementById("online");
    online.inject(div);
    online.draw();
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно вывести переменные online_txt и date_txt за пределы функции? Внутри функции log_txt_func() всё работает на ура, а за пределами не получается? После вывода данных мне нужно их передать в следующую функцию, для составления графика

Comment: взгляните на мой вариант, попробуйте.

Comment: И второй дубликат: [Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/719927/186999)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я попытался отрефакторить хоть как-то ваш код, он честно говоря был ужасен. Не уверен на счет рабочести, но можете протестить.

```
const dateTxtArr = [];
const onlineTxtArr = [];

async function logTxt(){
    let data = await fetch('log.txt');

    const logTxtArr = data.split("\r\n");

    for (const value of logTxtArr){
        const arr = value.split(' ==> ');
        dateTxtArr.push(arr[0]);
        onlineTxtArr.push(arr[2]);
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function(){
    await logTxt()
    let online = new liteChart("chart");
    online.setLabels(dateTxtArr);
    online.addLegend({"name": "Online", "stroke": "#3759d7", "fill": "#fff", "values": onlineTxtArr});
    let div = document.getElementById("online");
    online.inject(div);
    online.draw();
});
```

Comment: Соглашусь с @Shiki, код выглядит, как тренажёр для рефакторинга.

Comment: В данном варианте говорит Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined и ссылается на 9-ю строку этого кода

Comment: покажите ваш log.txt файлик

Comment: @opiums по идее пофиксил

Comment: 09.02.2019 15:55:27 ==> 1.236.16.1 ==> 6
09.02.2019 15:55:29 ==> 46.22.16.2 ==> 6
09.02.2019 15:55:30 ==> 46.22.10.4 ==> 6
...
Примерно так

Comment: там в названии пропа была ошибка `logTxt` вместо `logTxtReq` cтоял

Comment: Нашёл, lconst logTxtArr = logTxtReq.responseText.split("\r\n");

Comment: Всё таки тоже что то не так... [""] [undefined] - всё что выводится в консоли

Comment: у тебя где-то \r\n  стоит вообще?

Comment: 09.02.2019 15:55:27 ==> 1.236.16.1 ==> 6\r\n
09.02.201915:55:29 ==> 46.22.16.2 ==> 6\r\n
09.02.2019 15:55:30 ==> 46.22.10.4 ==> 6\r\n
 ...

Comment: Странно, если на нативном js запустить с этим текстом - все нормально, выводит `[ '09.02.2019 15:55:27',
  ' 09.02.201915:55:29',
  ' 09.02.2019 15:55:30' ] [ '6', '6', '6' ]`

Comment: Сейчас еще раз прорефакторю, с fetch попробуйте

Comment: На каких браузерах должно работать? залил сюда для теста всё: https://opiums.eu/chart/chart.html и заодно файл можно посмотреть

Comment: А где находится сам файл log.txt

Comment: там же, в той же директории

Comment: Странно, почему-то 304 отдает на запрос

Comment: https://opiums.eu/chart/log.txt не должно

Comment: Я поправил код, нашёл как вывести массив, но он теперь очень странный, и кроме того получаю что то типа ошибки "value below was evaluated just now", пока что решения не нашёл...

Answer (score 0):

Объявите эти переменные глобально и передавайте в функцию в качестве аргументов.

Comment: Каков тогда будет рабочий пример?

Comment: @opiums Поясните, Вы хотите, чтобы заработало то, что закомментировано в Вашем коде?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я хочу чтобы за пределами функции я мог использовать console.log(online_txt) и console.log(date_txt), после чего я смогу думаю передать их в следующую функцию

Comment: @opiums За пределами какой из четырёх, объявленных у Вас, функций Вы хотите иметь возможность использовать эти вызовы? Если речь о самом начале кода, добавьте третьей строкой `var date_txt;`

Comment: К сожалению это не выводит переменную за пределы функции, я проверял

Comment: @opiums Тогда сначала такой вопрос: оно у Вас вообще хоть в каком-то виде сейчас работает? Меня очень смущает объявление переменной с использованием этой же переменной здесь: `var date_txt = date_txt.split(",");`. И я всё ещё не пойму, о каких "пределах" идёт речь. Укажите номер строки в Вашем коде, из которой Вы хотите иметь доступ к этой переменной.

Comment: @opiums Я изучил Ваш код более детально. Я конечно не мастер в этом языке (который, кстати, следовало бы указать в метках), но, по-моему, здесь могут возникнуть проблемы не только с видимостью переменных.

Comment: Ну, я вроде отрефакторил, сверху по идее адекватно все должно работать, если изначально логика была правильной.