# Как дождаться окончания transition

Tags: javascript, html, анимация, события, transition

Есть вёрстка - https://mihinov.github.io/news/ 
При клике на меню, выходит оверлей, в котором есть календарик
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажать на крестик, то меню начнёт закрываться. Если во время закрытия пролистнуть вниз, то оверлей сожмётся, из-за того, что я сделал скрытие хедера при пролистывании вниз.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хотел бы сделать слушатель на окончание `transition`, но он вместо окончания анимация, срабатывает сразу в начале, при клике.
До того, как `transition` ещё не закончился `document.body` нельзя скроллить, после того, как сработало нужное событие, можно скроллить.
Я так сделал:

```js
function showMessage() {
    console.log(1); // тут нужный код
}
header__burger.addEventListener("transitionend", showMessage());
```

Как это работает: при каждом закрытии заново объявляется функция `showMessage()`, и задаётся слушатель с новой созданной функцией. Но проблема в том, что `transitionend` срабатывает сразу при закрытии. Как сделать так, чтобы `transitionend` срабатывал только при окончании анимации?

Comment: срабатывает, потому что вы сразу функцию вызываете

Comment: `header__burger.addEventListener("transitionend", showMessage)`

Comment: плохо понимаю, как это всё работает. Я сделал так: header__burger.addEventListener("transitionend", () => { showMessage(); }); Но таким образом сообщение выводится 4 раза(походу это все окончания transition) + сообщения увеличиваются в арифметической прогресси, потому что так я не могу удалить слушатель

Comment: уже больше похоже на правду

Comment: а вы точно на тот элемент обработчик вешаете? Надо тот, на котором непосредственно `transition`

Comment: @ThisMan Да, этому элементу я задаю отступ и на него кликаю

Comment: Я нашёл ресурс https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/transitionend ,  тут можно получать определённое свойство `propertyName` анимации, только я не понимаю как

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719926/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b6%d0%b5)

Comment: @РустамГимранов ответ я уже найден

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было не вызывать функцию при объявлении слушателя. А также нужно было удалять слушатель, после того, как сработал слушатель.

```js
function showMessage() {
    console.log(1);
    header__burger.removeEventListener("transitionend", showMessage);
}
header__burger.addEventListener("transitionend", showMessage);
```