# onClick функция в EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Возникла проблема вызова функции по хэндлеру onClick в ejs из get запроса. Функция должна лежать на сервере ибо будут выполнятся операции с бд и т.д. Как я пытался это сделать:

```js
app.get('/opencase', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    const values = Object.values(caseData.caseDataJson);
    const randomValue = values[parseInt(Math.random() * values.length)]
    function openCase() {
        switch (randomValue.name) {
            case "100 gold":
                console.log(randomValue.description)
                break;
            case "1000 gold":
                console.log(randomValue.description)
                break;
            case "10000 gold":
                console.log(randomValue.description)
                break;
            default:
                console.log("Oh, shit.")
                break;
        }
    };
    res.render('opencase', {
        user: req.user,
        clickHandler: openCase(),
        caseName: randomValue.name,
        caseDescription: randomValue.description,
    });
});
```

```html
    <button onclick="<%= clickHandler %>">Open</button>
```

Но функция вызывается не при клике, а при загрузке странице.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719926/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b6%d0%b5)

Comment: @РустамГимранов К сожалению нет. Сейчас пытаюсь это сделать через форму и пост запрос.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aerrity/fd393e5511106420fba0c9602cc05d35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это вызов функции:

```
...
clickHandler: openCase(),
...
```

Это назначение функции в качестве обработчика:

```
...
clickHandler: openCase,
...
```

Comment: Я убрал кавычки, но функция не срабатывает по нажатию.

Comment: может проблема в определении а .ejs файле?