# Как при первом нажатии переместить div в одно место, а при втором - обратно?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

На странице у меня находится кнопка и при первом нажатии на неё div элемент перемещается влево, а при повторном должен переместится обратно. Но div только выезжает, а при повторном нажатии на кнопку - 0 внимания.Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Вот пример кода:
HTML5:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="g.css" />
<script src="g.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="leftright1"></button>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS3:

```
button{height: 50px;width: 50px;position: fixed;top: 0px;left: 0px;}
div{height: 150px;width: 150px;background-color: blueviolet;position:fixed;top: 60px;right: 0px;}
```

JS:

```
function leftright1() {
    $("div").animate({right:"300px"},500)
    $("button").on(click,leftright2())
}
function leftright2() {
    $("div").animate({ right: "0px" }, 500);
    $("button").on(click,leftright1())
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719926/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b6%d0%b5)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

А вот так вам пойдет?

```js
function leftright1() {
    $("div").animate({right:"300px"},500)
    $('button').attr('onclick', 'leftright2()');
}
function leftright2() {
    $("div").animate({ right: "0px" }, 500);
    $('button').attr('onclick', 'leftright1()');
}
```

И еще у вас нету скобочек() в значении атрибута onclick: `<button onclick="leftright1()"></button>`