# Почему событие click срабатывает автоматически? JS

Tags: javascript, html, события

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

При назначении события `click` на какой-либо элемент при открытии веб-страницы этот самый клик срабатывает автоматически.

Ещё один случай, бывает, что `click`, назначенный конкретному элементу, срабатывает при клике вообще в любом месте документа.

Для примера:

```
<div id="block"></div>

let block = document.querySelector('#block');
block.addEventListener('click', Test());

function Test() {
   alert('Какое-то сообщение');
}
```

Так вот, при загрузке страницы сразу же сработает `alert`, без клика по элементу `block`.

По моим наблюдениям, если HTML элементов на странице несколько, то в таком случае `click` будет срабатывать по любому месту экрана и вызывать соответствующую функцию.

В чем проблема, и как её можно решить?

Comment: Небольшое замечание: функция тест не является функцией-конструктором, поэтому назначаться должна с маленькой буквы

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719926/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b6%d0%b5)

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы просто хотите вызвать функцию Test на событие "click":

```
block.addEventListener("click", Test)
```

Если Вы хотите передать параметры в функцию Test:

```
block.addEventListener("click", () => Test(arg1, arg2))

// или

block.addEventListener("click", function () { Test(arg1, arg2) })
```

*Отдельно стоит отметить что на вид Ваша функция `Test` не является конструктором, поэтому называть ее с большой буквы особого смысла нет.*

*Вы безусловно можете так делать, но это будет путать других разработчиков.*

Answer (score 2):

addEventListener вторым аргументом принимает функцию, а не результат выполнения работы функции

```js
const block = document.querySelector('#block');
block.addEventListener('click', test);

function test() {
   console.log('Какое-то сообщение');
}
```

```css
#block {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">Какой-то блок</div>
```

Comment: "а не результат ... функции" - ?? `function test() { return function() {alert("test");}; }` `block.addEventListener('click', test());`

Comment: @Igor мне кажется, такое новичкам не надо пытаться понять так рано, они только сильно запутаются

Comment: Если не передаёте вашей функции аргументов, то указывать её надо без скобок block.addEventListener('click', Test); А так как у вас, вы её по-сути запускаете сразу, а не привязываете к событию click.

Answer (score 1):

```
block.addEventListener('click', Test);
```

---

> click, назначенный конкретному элементу, срабатывает при клике вообще
> в любом месте документа

Этого в приведенном коде нет.